# It is only showing one value for each row

Tags: php

I have a phpfiddle here: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/get-rps

The problem I am getting is that in the `Total Marks` column, it is only display the total marks for the last question in all of the rows for all questions, rather than looping through all the total marks and displaying the correct total marks for each question. What am I doing wrong in the code?

Below is code:

```
<?php
$incorrect_ans = array(
                   array('A','C','D'),
                   array('B','C','D'),
                   array('A','B','D'),
                   array('A','B','C'));

$searchQuestionNo = array(
                   1,
                   2,
                   2,
                   3);

$totalMarks = array(
                   3,
                   5,
                   5,
                   2);

$ques_ans = array();    //to store incorrect answers against ques no.

$q_occ_count = array_count_values($searchQuestionNo);
foreach($searchQuestionNo as $key => $questionNo)
{
    if ( ! array_key_exists($questionNo, $ques_ans))
    {
        if($q_occ_count[$questionNo] === 1) //if a ques has only one correct ans
        {
            $ques_ans[$questionNo] = $incorrect_ans[$key];  //store the array of incorrect ans against the ques no as key 
        }
        else //if a ques has more than 1 correct ans
        {
            //find the intersection of incorrect_ans arrays for this ques
            $q_keys = array_keys($searchQuestionNo, $questionNo);
            $q_incorrect_ans = $incorrect_ans[$q_keys[0]];
            foreach($q_keys as $q_key) {
                $q_incorrect_ans = array_values(array_intersect($q_incorrect_ans, $incorrect_ans[$q_key]));
            }       
            $ques_ans[$questionNo] = $q_incorrect_ans;  //store the array of incorrect ans against the ques no as key
        }
    }
}
?>
<table border='1' id='penaltytbl'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class='questionnoth'>Question No.</th>
<th class='answerth'>Incorrect Answer</th>
<th class='marksth'>Total Marks</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php

foreach($ques_ans as $questionNo => $inc_ans)
{
    $q_row_span = count($inc_ans);
    $row_count = 0;
    ?>
    <tr class="questiontd">

        <!-- Question No -->
        <td class="questionnumtd q<?php echo $questionNo?>_qnum" rowspan="<?php echo $q_row_span ?>">
                <?php echo $questionNo?><input type="hidden" name="numQuestion" value="<?php echo $questionNo?>" />
        </td>

        <!-- first incorrect ans -->
        <td class="answertd"><?php echo $inc_ans[$row_count]; ?></td>

        <!-- Marks -->
       <td class="totalmarkstd" rowspan="<?php echo$q_row_span?>"><?php echo$totalMarks[$key]?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        //remaining incorrect answers in separate row (if any) follows here
    if($row_count < $q_row_span - 1) 
    {
        for($i=($row_count + 1); $i<$q_row_span; $i++) { ?>     
            <tr><td class="answertd"><?php echo $inc_ans[$i]; ?></td></tr>
    <?php
        }
    }
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: for the love of God and all things holy, don't write code like this!!!!  Keep your business logic and your display logic separate.  Figure out what you want to draw, then draw it in Javascript.  How long will you be away from this code before you have NO clue what the heck is going on in there? 2 days? 3?  I would love 15 points for the right answer here, but not badly enough to actually make sense of this mess.

Comment: Your problem is you're using `$key` to access `$totalMarks`, but it's long since been finished with the loop it's setup in. So, you get the last `$key` value, ie, `3`. I assume you want [`$questionNo`](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/wps-2f8) @Dr.Dredel - Calm down.

Comment: if ever there's anything to be worked up about in programming... this is it, so, I'd retort with @JaredFarrish - Excite Up!

Comment: @JaredFarrish I tried this before I posted the question, problem is that it still displays wrong marks for each question. Please look at table results here and you can see what is happening: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/get-rps

Comment: It's because once you copy your questions into `$ques_ans`, you lose the index that allows you to reference the same index value in `$totalMarks`. Normally, instead of three indexed arrays that "match" on index value, you see multidimensional arrays instead. So the first `$questionNo` is `1`, not `0`, etc. It's disorganized; refactor from a blank slate and just rethink how you're doing it, without trying to edit it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is your problem.

`<?php echo$totalMarks[$key]?>`

$key is set from your loop above, and is never reset in the bottom loop, so it is still has the last value from that loop.  I'm assuming it should be `<?php echo$totalMarks[$questionNo]?>`

Comment: I tried this before I posted the question, problem is that it still displays wrong marks for each question. Please look at table results here and you can see what is happening: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/get-rps

Comment: Have you got any more ideas on this?

Comment: Jared Farrish's comment above about losing the index is sound advice.  I would definitely work on re-factoring this code from the ground up.  Once you've reworked this code, if you still have problems, let me know.

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/get-rps. Now I got it working for these sets of answers but when I try another set of answers, it did not work. Can I ask if you know abetter way of changing the code above so that if a question has multiple correct answers, it does not show multiple steps as it does in the array? Imagine you tried to create your version of getting all answers and only keeping the incorrect answers and removing the correct answers, how would you write it up?